# Save API unicode response to zip file python

Tags: python, api, zip

When I hit post API, it is returning a zip file content as an output (which is in unicode form) and I want to save those content in zipfile locally.

How can I save the same?

**Trials** :

**Try 1:**

```
`//variable data containing API response. (i.e data = response.text)
f = open('test.zip', 'wb')
f.write(data.encode('utf8'))
f.close()`
```

Above code creating zip file. But the file is corrupted one.

**Try 2**

`with zipfile.ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
      myzip.write(data.decode("utf8"))`

Above code giving me an error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 97: ordinal not in range(128)`

Can anyone help me to resolve the same?

Comment: `f = open('test.zip', 'w')` you should open your file in `'wb'` mode when reading/writing binary data

Comment: @Nullman : I tried with `wb` as well, this is creating corrupted zip file. It is giving `An error occured while loading archive` while unziping the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for above problem. May be someone in future wants the same. So writing answer for my own question.

`response.content` instead of `response.text` resolved my problem.

```
import requests
response = requests.request("POST", <<url>>, <<payload>>, <<headers>>, verify=False)
data = response.content

f = open('test.zip', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: this doesnt zip the file, just the extension is zip.